# Is there a way to see all changes between open-liberty versions

Tags: open-liberty

We are running quite an older version of OL, and we would like to start upgrading the version, but since there has been so many newer versions, and the version we are on is not even on the docs anymore, how would we be able to get a list between two versions and see breaking changes/new features?

Tried going through the version blog posts, but seems like a long process to do a version upgrade. I was hoping to do a version diff, and get a breakdown of all the fixes/changes between the versions. Since the application is running with a munch of microprofiled systems there is a lot to upgrade across the board

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general OpenLiberty is designed with [Zero-migration architecture principle](https://openliberty.io/docs/22.0.0.3/zero-migration-architecture.html) and in most cases your application should run fine in the new runtime. I'd strongly suggest to try it, as it will be much easier to debug and solve any issues you will see that go through all release documents. ;-)

Info about releases you can find here - https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/releases

Comment: Thanks @Gas so if we upgrade just the versions we "should" have minimal changes. But if we change the features we use, that's where the major changes may come? There isn't a way to see all the changes a version had fixed though I assume besides reading each blog post?

Comment: Each Open Liberty release has a changes file which lists the changes in it, so you could download them all and look at the changes file. However I suspect you are concerned about breaking changes and as Gas says there should not be any: https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/zero-migration-architecture.html

Comment: @noobcoder probably the biggest change is between Java EE 8 and Jakarta 9.1 See here https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/diff/jakarta-ee-diff.html, but you dont have to use latest Jakarta to use latest OpenLiberty. Even latest version still fully supports Javaee-8